# Geth syncing for 24 hours, still not done

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync

I downloaded Geth 1.6.6 and ran it to sync the blockchain. It's been 24 hours, the chaindata folder is 12.4gb and it's still going. When should I expect it to be done? Is this normal (the website that I reading from said it would take "from 20 minutes to several hours") or have I done something wrong? I used the command `geth --rpc --fast --cache=1024`, if that helps. Fairly new to this, so not 100% sure what's happening.

Comment: Similar info here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18709/geth-chaindata-copied-syncd-keystore-account-updated-balance-0-heavy-act?noredirect=1#comment20162_18709

Comment: This is a repeating pattern, but there is no "official" statement yet as to the root cause. Seems to be linked to the power of the machine, a dual core with 4gig RAM seems insufficient. What do you use?

Comment: I have an Intel i7-6700HQ cpu and 16gb of ram. Fairly sure it's quadcore, but not 100% sure

Comment: @Reece Jocumsen it is quad core indeed and it should be enough to power, are you mining with GPU or CPU ?

Comment: I haven't started mining yet, all I did was type 'geth --rpc --fast --cache=1024' into cmd and let it run. I read the post I was linked to and decided to delete the files I'd already had and try again and see how that turns out.

Comment: Machine is a quad core, yes. You can try --cache=2048, you have enough RAM. When the geth --fast process started, it will load up to 25Gig of chaindata to your harddisk. Depending on your network speed, it can take days. Other people reported, that turning off the router or stopping geth throughout the process (until it is fully sync'd), may impact the download. So probably you want to let it run, until fully sync'd.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your help. Will --cache=2048 speed it up or does it do something else?

Comment: What is the type of your disk? Perhaps not ssd?

Comment: It's an ssd, yeah. Plenty of space on it too. I had 'geth --fast --cache=1024 console' running for a few days, got to around 3.99 mil (24.5 gig chaindata folder), and now when I type in 'eth.syncing' it says false. It's still importing new state entries and everything but it's not syncing, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

First Check syncing progress by

```
$ geth attach
> eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 2272408,
  highestBlock: 2326493,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 2265791
}
```

With every time you run `eth.syncing` you should see number increased. Syncing would finish when currentBlock reach highestBlock.

**Important issue**

If you saw currentBlock isn't increasing anymore at last few hundreds remaining blocks, one of most important problems is your system time!
Try to enable network time synchronisation on your computer and restart geth after that may solve your problem.

You can use following command to enable NTP on Ubuntu.

`timedatectl set-ntp true`